# C# extract words using regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I've found a lot of examples of how to **check** something using regex, or how to split text using regular expressions.

But how can I extract words out of a string ?

Example:

```
aaaa 12312 <asdad> 12334 </asdad>
```

Lets say I have something like this, and I want to extract all the numbers [0-9]* and put them in a list.

Or if I have 2 different kind of elements:

```
aaaa 1234 ...... 1234 ::::: asgsgd
```

And I want to `choose digits that come after .....` and `words that come after ::::::`

Can I extract these strings in a single regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, you can do this using capturing parentheses:

```
string input = "aaaa 1234 ...... 1234 ::::: asgsgd";
string regex = @"\.\.\.\. (\d+) ::::: (\w+)";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, regex);

if (m.Success) {
    int numberAfterDots = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
    string wordAfterColons = m.Groups[2].Value;
    // ... Do something with these values
}
```

But the first part you asked (extract all the numbers) is a bit easier:

```
string input = "aaaa 1234 ...... 1234 ::::: asgsgd";
var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value))
                   .ToList();
```

Now `numbers` will be a list of integers.

Comment: So Each expression inside a ( ) will be grouped ?

Comment: Yes. Notice that the group numbering starts at `1`. Also see my latest edit to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for your first problem:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = "aaaa 12312 <asdad> 12334 </asdad>";

            Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]+");

            foreach (var match in reg.Matches(data))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**For your specific examples:**

```
    string firstString = "aaaa 12312 <asdad> 12334 </asdad>";
    Regex firstRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Digits>[\d]+)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (firstRegex.IsMatch(firstString))
    {
        MatchCollection firstMatches = firstRegex.Matches(firstString);
        foreach (Match match in firstMatches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Digits: " + match.Groups["Digits"].Value);
        }
    }

    string secondString = "aaaa 1234 ...... 1234 ::::: asgsgd";
    Regex secondRegex = new Regex(@"([\.]+\s(?<Digits>[\d]+))|([\:]+\s(?<Words>[a-zA-Z]+))", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    if (secondRegex.IsMatch(secondString))
    {
        MatchCollection secondMatches = secondRegex.Matches(secondString);
        foreach (Match match in secondMatches)
        {
            if (match.Groups["Digits"].Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digits: " + match.Groups["Digits"].Value);
            }
            if (match.Groups["Words"].Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Words: " + match.Groups["Words"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps. The output is:

```
Digits: 12312
Digits: 12334
Digits: 1234
Words: asgsgd
```

Comment: Explicit captures aren't necessary, but they let you reorder your parentheses groups and you don't have to change the code, since you're using NAMES for the groups instead of ordinal positioning. That's why I use "Digits" and "Words" instead of \1 and \2 for my match groups. The naming of the explicit capture group is done by adding "?<Name>" right inside the "(", all without quotes of course.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do nicely!

```
var text = "aaaa 12312 <asdad> 12334 </asdad>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\w+");

var arrayOfMatched = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arrayOfMatched));
```

\w+ Matches consecutive word characters. Then we just selected the values out of the list of matches and turn them into an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Regex phoneregex = new Regex("[0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
    String unicornCanneryDirectory = "unicorn cannery 483-8627 cha..."
    String numbersToCall = "";

    //the second argument is where to begin within the match, 
    //we probably want 0, the first character
    Match matchIterator = phoneregex.Match(unicornCanneryDirectory , 0);
    //Success tells us if matchIterator has another match or not
    while( matchIterator.Sucess){
      String aResult = matchIterator.Result();
      //we could manipulate our match now but I'm going to concatenate them all for later
      numbersToCall  += aResult + " ";

      matchIterator = matchIterator.NextMatch();
    }

    // use my concatenated matches now
    String message = "Unicorn rights activists demand more sparkles in the unicorn canneries under the new law...";
    phoneDialer.MassCallWithAutomatedMessage(aResult, message );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex itemsRegex = new Regex(@"(\d*)");
MatchCollection matches = itemsRegex.Matches(text);

int[] values = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Value)).ToArray();
```